# difference between "/dev/disk1s3" and "/dev/rdisk1s3"

Tags: macos

When I open with "/dev/disk1s3",it said "Resource busy".But when I open with "/dev/rdisk1s3",it is ok.What is the difference between "/dev/disk1s3" and "/dev/rdisk1s3"?

```
open("/dev/disk1s3", O_RDONLY);//Resource busy
open("/dev/rdisk1s3", O_RDONLY);//ok
```

How to open with "/dev/disk1s3"?

Comment: Relevant answer on another Stack Exchange site: https://superuser.com/questions/631592/why-is-dev-rdisk-about-20-times-faster-than-dev-disk-in-mac-os-x

Comment: @bnaecker Yes, I know this. But that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I assumed you were interested in the difference between the two. If you want an actual solution, you'll need to provide some more details. Open how? What programming language? Can you provide code demonstrating your error?

Comment: @bnaecker I edited it.